# Xamarin Forms: Not able to create a left aligned 2 column grid

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a xamarin form using the grid and stackLayout as below. On both the scenarios the second column control is not starting uniformly aligned vertically.

XAML using GRID control:

```
<BoxView Style="{StaticResource separator}"></BoxView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Style="{StaticResource layoutTitle}">
            <Label Text="MANAGE PROFILE"  Style="{StaticResource labelTitle}"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    <BoxView  Style="{StaticResource separator}"></BoxView>

    <Grid BackgroundColor="{StaticResource whiteBackgroundColor}">
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="44"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="1"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="44"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="1"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="44"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="1"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="44"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="1"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="44"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="1"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource whiteBackgroundColor}" Style="{StaticResource layoutSpacingFormEntry}">  
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="AddressLine1" Style="{StaticResource labelStandard}"></Label>
            <Entry  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Placeholder="required" Text="{Binding AddressLine1.Value}">
                    <Entry.Effects>
                        <effects:EntryNoBorderEffect />
                    </Entry.Effects>
                    <Entry.Behaviors>
                        <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="TextChanged" Command="{Binding AddressLine1.TriggerValidationCommand}" />
                    </Entry.Behaviors>
                    <Entry.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger TargetType="Entry" Binding="{Binding AddressLine1.IsValid}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="behaviors:EntryErrorColorBehavior.LineColor" Value="{StaticResource ErrorColor}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Entry.Triggers>
             </Entry>
         </StackLayout>
         <BoxView  Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Style="{StaticResource separator}"></BoxView>

         <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource whiteBackgroundColor}" Style="{StaticResource layoutSpacingFormEntry}">
            <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="AddressLine2" Style="{StaticResource labelStandard}"></Label>
            <Entry Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Placeholder="required" Text="{Binding AddressLine2.Value}">
                <Entry.Effects>
                    <effects:EntryNoBorderEffect />
                </Entry.Effects>
                <Entry.Behaviors>
                    <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="TextChanged" Command="{Binding AddressLine2.TriggerValidationCommand}" />
                </Entry.Behaviors>
                <Entry.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger TargetType="Entry" Binding="{Binding AddressLine2.IsValid}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="behaviors:EntryErrorColorBehavior.LineColor" Value="{StaticResource ErrorColor}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Entry.Triggers>
            </Entry>
        </StackLayout>
        <BoxView  Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Style="{StaticResource separator}"></BoxView>

        <StackLayout Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource whiteBackgroundColor}" Style="{StaticResource layoutSpacingFormEntry}">
            <Label Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Text="Suburb" Style="{StaticResource labelStandard}"></Label>
            <Entry Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Placeholder="required" Text="{Binding Suburb.Value}">
                <Entry.Effects>
                    <effects:EntryNoBorderEffect />
                </Entry.Effects>
                <Entry.Behaviors>
                    <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="TextChanged" Command="{Binding Suburb.TriggerValidationCommand}" />
                </Entry.Behaviors>
                <Entry.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger TargetType="Entry" Binding="{Binding Suburb.IsValid}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="behaviors:EntryErrorColorBehavior.LineColor" Value="{StaticResource ErrorColor}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Entry.Triggers>
            </Entry>
        </StackLayout>

        <BoxView Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Style="{StaticResource separator}"></BoxView>

        <StackLayout Grid.Row="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource whiteBackgroundColor}" Style="{StaticResource layoutSpacingFormEntry}">  
            <Label Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Text="State" Style="{StaticResource labelStandard}" ></Label>
            <Picker Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                    Title="Select" SelectedItem="{Binding State.Value}">
                <Picker.ItemsSource>
                    <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                      <x:String>NSW</x:String>
                      <x:String>WA</x:String>
                      <x:String>QLD</x:String>
                      <x:String>SA</x:String>
                      <x:String>VIC</x:String>
                      <x:String>TAS</x:String>
                    </x:Array>
                  </Picker.ItemsSource>
            </Picker>
         </StackLayout>
         <BoxView Grid.Row="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Style="{StaticResource separator}"></BoxView>

         <StackLayout Grid.Row="8" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource whiteBackgroundColor}" Style="{StaticResource layoutSpacingFormEntry}">
            <Label Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="0" Text="Post Code" Style="{StaticResource labelStandard}"></Label>
            <Entry Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Placeholder="required" Text="{Binding PostCode.Value}">
                <Entry.Effects>
                    <effects:EntryNoBorderEffect />
                </Entry.Effects>
                <Entry.Behaviors>
                    <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="TextChanged" Command="{Binding PostCode.TriggerValidationCommand}" />
                </Entry.Behaviors>
                <Entry.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger TargetType="Entry" Binding="{Binding PostCode.IsValid}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="behaviors:EntryErrorColorBehavior.LineColor" Value="{StaticResource ErrorColor}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Entry.Triggers>
            </Entry>
        </StackLayout>
        <BoxView Grid.Row="9" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Style="{StaticResource separator}"></BoxView>
    </Grid>
```

XAML using StackLayout,

```
<BoxView Style="{StaticResource separator}"></BoxView>
          <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Style="{StaticResource layoutTitle}" BackgroundColor="#EFEFF4">
            <Label Text="MANAGE PROFILE"  Style="{StaticResource labelTitle}"></Label>
          </StackLayout>
          <BoxView  Style="{StaticResource separator}"></BoxView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource whiteBackgroundColor}" Style="{StaticResource layoutSpacingFormEntry}">
            <Label Text="AddressLine1" Style="{StaticResource labelStandard}" WidthRequest="100"></Label>
            <Entry x:Name="AddressLine1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Placeholder="required" Text="{Binding AddressLine1.Value}">
                <Entry.Effects>
                    <effects:EntryNoBorderEffect />
                </Entry.Effects>
                <Entry.Behaviors>
                    <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="TextChanged" Command="{Binding AddressLine1.TriggerValidationCommand}" />
                </Entry.Behaviors>
                <Entry.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger TargetType="Entry" Binding="{Binding AddressLine1.IsValid}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="behaviors:EntryErrorColorBehavior.LineColor" Value="{StaticResource ErrorColor}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Entry.Triggers>
            </Entry>
        </StackLayout>
        <BoxView  Style="{StaticResource separator}"></BoxView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource whiteBackgroundColor}" Style="{StaticResource layoutSpacingFormEntry}">
            <Label Text="AddressLine2" Style="{StaticResource labelStandard}" WidthRequest="100"></Label>
            <Entry x:Name="AddressLine2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Placeholder="required" Text="{Binding AddressLine2.Value}">
                <Entry.Effects>
                    <effects:EntryNoBorderEffect />
                </Entry.Effects>
                <Entry.Behaviors>
                    <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="TextChanged" Command="{Binding AddressLine2.TriggerValidationCommand}" />
                </Entry.Behaviors>
                <Entry.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger TargetType="Entry" Binding="{Binding AddressLine2.IsValid}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="behaviors:EntryErrorColorBehavior.LineColor" Value="{StaticResource ErrorColor}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Entry.Triggers>
            </Entry>
        </StackLayout>
        <BoxView  Style="{StaticResource separator}"></BoxView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource whiteBackgroundColor}" Style="{StaticResource layoutSpacingFormEntry}">
            <Label Text="Suburb" Style="{StaticResource labelStandard}" WidthRequest="100"></Label>
            <Entry x:Name="Suburb" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Placeholder="required" Text="{Binding Suburb.Value}">
                <Entry.Effects>
                    <effects:EntryNoBorderEffect />
                </Entry.Effects>
                <Entry.Behaviors>
                    <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="TextChanged" Command="{Binding Suburb.TriggerValidationCommand}" />
                </Entry.Behaviors>
                <Entry.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger TargetType="Entry" Binding="{Binding Suburb.IsValid}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="behaviors:EntryErrorColorBehavior.LineColor" Value="{StaticResource ErrorColor}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Entry.Triggers>
            </Entry>
        </StackLayout>

        <BoxView  Style="{StaticResource separator}"></BoxView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource whiteBackgroundColor}" Style="{StaticResource layoutSpacingFormEntry}">
            <Label  x:Name="State" Text="State" Style="{StaticResource labelStandard}" WidthRequest="100"></Label>
            <Picker x:Name="pickerState" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                    Title="Select" SelectedItem="{Binding State.Value}">
                <Picker.ItemsSource>
                    <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                      <x:String>NSW</x:String>
                      <x:String>WA</x:String>
                      <x:String>QLD</x:String>
                      <x:String>SA</x:String>
                      <x:String>VIC</x:String>
                      <x:String>TAS</x:String>
                    </x:Array>
                  </Picker.ItemsSource>
            </Picker>
        </StackLayout>
        <BoxView  Style="{StaticResource separator}"></BoxView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource whiteBackgroundColor}" Style="{StaticResource layoutSpacingFormEntry}">
            <Label Text="Post Code" Style="{StaticResource labelStandard}" WidthRequest="100"></Label>
            <Entry x:Name="PostCode" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Placeholder="required" Text="{Binding PostCode.Value}">
                <Entry.Effects>
                    <effects:EntryNoBorderEffect />
                </Entry.Effects>
                <Entry.Behaviors>
                    <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="TextChanged" Command="{Binding PostCode.TriggerValidationCommand}" />
                </Entry.Behaviors>
                <Entry.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger TargetType="Entry" Binding="{Binding PostCode.IsValid}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="behaviors:EntryErrorColorBehavior.LineColor" Value="{StaticResource ErrorColor}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Entry.Triggers>
            </Entry>
        </StackLayout>
        <BoxView Style="{StaticResource separator}"></BoxView>
```

On both the scenarios the second column is starting based on the text value. Even if I add HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand", I'm not able to get the all the form controls vertically aligned in the second column to start with.

Getting the UI as below,

I have added both the controls as fo now in XAML. The top section of form is using GRID control. The below repeated section is using the StackLayout control

[image]

Please let me know what am I doing wrong here

Comment: Why don’t you use a TableView for this?

Answer (score 0):

you have set the column width as "*". if you want to vertically align your controls you need to set the column with size like "50*" , "50*" or "60*" ,"40*" . it will set the width in %.

Comment: Adding 50* as the column width in the column definition didn't help